# AngularJs - How to write testable controllers with private Methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I'm trying to write a test for one of my controller, using angular.js + jasmine.

Let's say I have a controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('MyCtrl', function() {
    this.myFunc = function() {
        // ...
    };

    activate();

    function activate() {
        this.myFunc();
    }
});
```

This controller have a function called activate() that is called when the controller is created.

How can I write a test for the activate() function? (like this: when the controller is created, should call a controller function "myFunc()")

I tried to write something like this:

```
describe('activate() controller', function() {
    it('should call function myFunc', inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        var locals     = {$scope: $rootScope.$new()};
        var controller = $controller('MyCtrl', locals);

        spyOn(controller, 'myFunc').toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
}
```

But I get the error:

> Expected spy myFunc to have been called.

I think at the point I create my spy, the controller already called the activate function.

Is there a way to test a controller like this?

Comment: Are you loading in the module before each test?

Comment: I think only way you can test this is if the myFunc is changing the state of the controller in someway that can be confirmed

Comment: Yes, I think @Chandermani is correct.  You would have to `spy` on the `controller` reference *before* the call to `$controller`.  Then the spy would be able to record what happens in its contructor.

Comment: yes, I load the module. @DavinTryon Can you post a code example?

Comment: A code example of what?

Comment: "You would have to spy on the controller reference before the call to $controller"

Comment: To call toHaveBeenCalled the spy has to be created on the target object before the call is made. In your example the constructor is where the call is made. The constructor returns the instance that you want to spy on. Do you see the problem? By the time you are setting up the spy, the call to myFunc has already been invoked.

Answer (score 1):

The code example you have above executes the myFunc method upon initialization. Therefore, by the time you attach the spy, it has already been executed. The better way of testing would be to inspect what transformations the myFunc has performed.

If the method were part of a service, you could setup your spy in your inject, and then initialize the controller and expect the service method to have been called.